# jquery slider with dragable scroller and back next buttons

Tags: jquery

I need a jquery slider image gallery where the images move with a scrollbar slider and also when next and previous buttons are clicked, I found various scripts with the scrollbar but haven't been able to relate the buttons. I would really appreciate it if you could help me.

Regards,
Roni

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen JAlbum?  There are many different types and themes for javascript photo galleries.  The software automatically generates the gallery for you (drag and drop images into it).

http://jalbum.net/